# Golang loop until key pressed

Tags: go, keyboard

I'm using Go and I need to be able to run a loop until a certain key is pressed.  Are there any libraries or is there any functionality that allows this to happen? I just need to detect if a key is *down* on each iteration of the loop.  I've tried using azul3d, but it wasn't quite what I was looking for...

This is what I'm hoping for:

```
exit := false
for !exit {
    exit = watcher.Down(keyboard.Space)
}
```

or something similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [keyboard](https://github.com/julienroland/keyboard-termbox) with its [termbox](https://github.com/nsf/termbox-go) backend, like this:

```
package main

import "github.com/julienroland/keyboard-termbox"
import "fmt"
import term "github.com/nsf/termbox-go"

func main() {
    running := true
    err := term.Init()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    defer term.Close()

    kb := termbox.New()
    kb.Bind(func() {
        fmt.Println("pressed space!")
        running = false
    }, "space")

    for running {
        kb.Poll(term.PollEvent())
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, will try that!  :)

Comment: It doesn't seem to work - am I doing something wrong?  I'm just looping until the space bar is pressed, but it never recognizes when I press the space bar.

Comment: What operating system? Are you testing this from the terminal?

Comment: Windows 10, and yes.

Comment: Never mind, I seem to have figured it out. edit - didn't see your comment or updated answer, woops.  Anyways, it works.  Thanks!

Comment: Actually, this might not be possible, but could `kb.Poll(term.PollEvent())` be nonblocking and only fire if a key is pressed?

Comment: `kb.Poll` is not blocking, but `term.PollEvent` is.  The [docblock](https://github.com/nsf/termbox-go/blob/master/api.go#L305) for `PollEvent` says this: `Wait for an event and return it. This is a blocking function call.`

Comment: If you don't want to block the current goroutine, just spawn a new one and poll it from there.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use this `fmt.Scanln()` instead